# Is there a way I can update my Meteor app without wiping my MongoDB on the production server?

Tags: meteor

I'm installing my SSL certificate and need to run `mupx setup` and `mupx deploy` to get it to work.

However, doing this and then deploying my app will wipe my MongoDB on my production server and users lose all of their accounts. It would be a nightmare.

I simply run `mupx deploy` after making fixed to my Meteor app to update my app. However, when installing my SSL certificate (according to the Mup documentation) I have to run `mupx setup` to get it to work.

Is there a way I can do this without wiping my user database on my deployment server?

Comment: Why not just backup your mongodb beforehand and then swap it back in after the upgrade?

Comment: ideally in prod you should have a separate MongoDB that you link to your app with the MONGO_URL flag.

Comment: @MichelFloyd I just tried to back up MongoDB using the traditional way via SSH, but apparently, it's empty. Is there a special way to do this for Meteor collections?

Comment: Should be something like `$ mongodump --host 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 --db meteor` - depending on your host and port